# How to know the MQ Queue Manager Channel Name in IBM MQ explorer?

Tags: ibm-mq

Could anyone please help me to know, how can i know the MQ Queue Manager Channel Name.

I have created a local MQ queue, but when i'm trying to connect to it from OSB, its asking for channel name as well.

I'm having both IBM MQ and OSB on same windows system.

Comment: Try selecting `mqBindingModeType`

Comment: Or create a server connection channel with whatever name you like.

Comment: Using Oracle Service Bus on the same machine with the queue manager, you can tell it to use "binding mode" using the setting I provided above to connect locally instead of via TCP/IP using a MQ Channel.

Comment: You said both MQ and OSB are on the same server, did you try enabling "mqBindingModeType", what was the result?

Comment: Yes i tried, but i was not able to get the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either create a new server connection channel from MQ Explorer (or using runmqsc commands) or connect using the "**SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN**" channel, which exists by default on all queue managers.

To list all channels in the queue manager, do

> runmqsc *queuemanager_name*
>
> DISPLAY CHANNEL (*)

To see only Server connection channels,

> DISPLAY CHANNEL (*) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do NOT use the SYSTEM.* channel.  Create a new one (i.e. MY.APPL.CHL) and use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs. i have created a new server connection channel nut its in inactive state, i tried to start it 2-3 times from MQ explorer.

Comment: The server-connection channel is ready to be used when it is in INACTIVE state. It will go into running status when your client application connects to it and not at any other time.